# Cannot add instance method to a Ruby-on-Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a new instance method to one of my models. Here is the model:

```
# app/models/server.rb
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.zzz()
  end

end
```

Herre is the controller:

```
class ServersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @server = Server.new
    @server.zzz
  end

end
```

When I call the `new` method I get this error:

```
undefined method `zzz' for #<Server:0x0055f64a3c4cb8>
```

Why can't I add an extra instance method to the `Server` class this way? I am using Rails 4.2 on a Debian stretch system.

Comment: `self.zzz()` is class method not instance method. you can remove the `self` and call the instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to add a new instance method to one of my models.

You added a class method instead and you can't call a class method (declared with `self` before the name) on an instance. You can either call the `#zzz` method on the class directly like this:

```
Server.zzz
```

or redefine `zzz` to be an instance method:

```
def zzz
end
```

to be able to call it on `@server`.